# How to find $\int {1\over x^2+x+1}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have this indefinite integral to evaluate:
$$\int {1\over x^2+x+1}\,dx$$
I thought it should be solved with IBP but it wouldn't work. I would appreciate any help or hint as for what identities I should use, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint:

Complete the square: $$x^2 + x + 1 = x^2 + x + \frac 14 + \frac 34 = \left(x+\frac 12\right)^2 + \left(\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^2$$

Now put $x+\dfrac 12 = \dfrac{\sqrt 3}2 \tan \theta$.

Comment: I have actually arrived at it, but didn't know how to derive any integration identity...

Comment: See my post for the suggested substitution.

Comment: Use the identity: $\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2 \theta$, and in this problem, we have $ dx = \frac{\sqrt{3}}2 \sec^2 \theta\,d\theta$.

Comment: You can also just rearrange it to obtain the definition of the derivative of arctangent through non trig based substitution

Comment: @amWhy: I don't think we can handle the integrand with any other ways. Good points indeed!